# SH - Save command with parameter in variable

Tags: sh

Im trying make an script which can find and store specific type files in a folder.

When I run myScript.sh:
`$ ./myScript.sh *.txt`

It should save in files.txt all files with .txt extension but doesn't work for me. Only save first file.

myScript.sh:

```
var=`find $1`
for file in $var
do
echo $var >> files.txt
done
```

That's an example for practice

Comment: You pass multiple args to `myScript` (assuming that `*.txt` expands to match multiple files), but only use the first, and you are treating that as a directory.   What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: That's could be my problem. If i have file1.txt file2.txt and file3.jpg, i want to store in a new file the files names ended in .txt. I didn't know i got multiple args with *.txt. I think it was an array with data.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
for file in $@
do
echo "$file" >> files.txt
done
```

Using `$@`, you can get all the arguments in the script that you pass.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop at all. Just redirect the output of `find` to your file.

```
find . "$1" >> files.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i fix this issue passing .txt instead *.txt and changing my script like this:

```
$ ./myScript.sh *.txt

var=`find *$1`
for file in $var
do
echo $var >> files.txt
done
```

It works for me.

Thank you all for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are passing arguments to the script at all.  If you want all the files in the current directory whose name ends in ".txt", you could do either:

```
ls *.txt > files.txt
```

or

```
find . -name '*.txt' > files.txt  # descends the directory tree
```

or (not standard)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' > files.txt
```

None of these will handle files with embedded newlines particularly well, but that use case is not handled well when storing names in a file.